# Guardar el número de una línea concreta de un txt en una variable

Tags: batch

**Objetivo**: Quedarme con una parte muy concreta de un txt. La forma de diferenciar lo que me quiero quedar es gracias a las palabras "dependencies" y "devDependencies".

Ejemplo del txt:

```
{ 
    "name": "app", 
    "description": "Aplicacion", 
    "version": "3.378.10-SNAPSHOT", 
    "private": true, 
    "dependencies":     { 
        "parent": "1.28.4", 
        "confirmation": "1.28.0", 
        "paymentdata": "1.12.1", 
     }, 
    "devDependencies":     { 
        "parent": "1.28.4", 
        "confirmation": "1.28.0", 
        "paymentdata": "1.12.1", 
    }
}
```

Me quiero quedar sólo con la parte que está en "dependencies" y eliminar lo que hay antes y después.

Mi planteamiento es saber la línea en la que está "dependencies" y "devDependencies" y luego con un for recorrer el fichero y si la línea en la que me encuentro está entre "dependencies" y "devDependencies" lo guardo en un nuevo txt, y si no, no hago nada, teniendo un nuevo txt con:

```
"parent": "1.28.4", 
"confirmation": "1.28.0", 
"paymentdata": "1.12.1",
```

He llegado a saber la línea con esta instrucción:

```
type %nombreFichero% | find /n /i "dependencies"
```

pero me arroja 3 resultados:

```
[6]    "dependencies":     {
[340]    "devDependencies":     {
[520]        "checkDependencies": "node \"./scripts/app.js\"",
```

lo que me interesaría guardar en una varible es únicamente el primer 6, para luego utilizarlo, pero no se me ocurre como.

Quizá haya una mejor manera para eliminar las líneas que comento, pero a mi se me ha ocurrido así.

Cualquier sugerencia que haga más fácil/legible/optimo para conseguir el objetivo será bien recibida.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me ha salido de esta manera:

1.- Guardo la búsqueda de dependencies en linea.txt

```
find /n "dependencies" %nombreFichero% > linea.txt
```

Ahora linea.txt contiene lo siguiente:

```
---------- 2023.10.25-3.378.10.JSON
[6]    "dependencies":     {
```

2.- Limpio el fichero para quedarme únicamente con el número de la línea y lo guardo en la variable inicio

```
for /F "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%i in (linea.txt) do (
@echo %%i
set inicio=%%i
)
```

Compruebo con echo que la variable inicio contiene 6, por lo que la puedo utilizar para empezar desde aquí.

No sé si es buena solución o es un poco liosa y se puede hacer más rápido y mejor.

Gracias.

Comment: También puedes usar el `for` con comandos. De igual manera que con los archivos. Lo único que cambia es que escribes el comando entre comillas dobles. `for /f "opciones" %%i in ("comando") do ...`

Comment: Quise decir simples. Por ejemplo `for /f "opciones" %%i in ('comando') do ...`

Answer (score 0):

Algo que podrías hacer fácilmente con un lenguaje de programación es difícil en este lenguaje de scripts. Por ese motivo creo que los BAT o CMD son limitados. Así que una primera opción sería utilizar un lenguaje de programación, Python por ejemplo.

No es necesario que uses [`type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/type) y lo redirijas. El comando [`find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find) puede leer el contenido de un archivo.  Su sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
find [/v] [/c] [/n] [/i] [/off[line]] <"string"> [[<drive>:][<path>]<filename>[...]]
```

Además la opción `/i` hace que no distinga mayúsculas y minúsculas. En el primer resultado que obtienes *dependencies* está en minúscula y en los siguientes la *D* está en mayúscula. Así que con quitar esa opción ya estarías obteniendo un solo resultado.

El comando quedaría así:

```
find /n "dependencies" %nombreFichero%
```

Comment: Gracias Mateo, pero... ¿cómo asigno el resultado a una variable? Estoy probando esto, pero no me sale....
```set inicio=find /n "dependencies" %nombreFichero%```

Comment: @isleca aquí tienes algunas maneras https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340018/13419694